# Silverlight Windows Phone 7 ItemsControl Data Binding

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, windows-phone-7

I'm working on an app for WP7. I have a collection of objects, which each have some properties we need to show on screen. I'm sorry, but to really explain it, this will be code-heavy.

MyGrouping Class:

```
public class MyListGrouping : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyListGrouping( )
    {
        _Title = "";
        _Group = new ObservableCollection<MyList>( );
    }

    private string _Title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _Title; }
        set
        {
            _Title = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged( "Title" );
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MyList> _Group;
    public ObservableCollection<MyList> Group
    {
        get { return _Group; }
        set
        {
            _Group = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged( "Group" );
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged( string propertyName )
    {
        if ( PropertyChanged != null )
            PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );
    }
}
```

MyList Class:

```
public class MyList : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyList( ){}

    private string _DisplayName;
    public string DisplayName
    {
        get{return _DisplayName;}
        set
        {
            _DisplayName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged( "DisplayName" );
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged( string propertyName )
    {
        if ( PropertyChanged != null )
            PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );
    }
}
```

Now for the 2 separate User Controls in Silverlight.

```
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemContainer" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListGroups}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                    <!--Only works if we don't bind here for some reason-->
                    <base:MyListView ListGroup="{Binding Group}" Title="{Binding Title}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>

    public partial class MyListGroupingView : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ListGroupsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( "ListGroups", typeof( ObservableCollection<MyListGrouping> ), typeof( MyListGroupingView ), new PropertyMetadata( null ) );

    public MyListGroupingView( )
    {
        InitializeComponent( );
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyListGrouping> ListGroups
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<MyListGrouping>)GetValue( ListGroupsProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( ListGroupsProperty, value ); }
    }

    private void UserControl_Loaded( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
    {
        MyListGrouping aList = new MyListGrouping( ) { Title = "A" };
        aList.Group.Add( new MyList( ) { DisplayName = "Ant" } );
        aList.Group.Add( new MyList( ) { DisplayName = "Art" } );

        MyListGrouping bList = new MyListGrouping( ) { Title = "B" };
        bList.Group.Add( new MyList( ) { DisplayName = "Bob" } );
        bList.Group.Add( new MyList( ) { DisplayName = "Billy" } );

        ObservableCollection<MyListGrouping> collection = new ObservableCollection<MyListGrouping>( );
        collection.Add( aList );
        collection.Add( bList );

        ListGroups = collection;
    }
}
```

And the UI element that it uses:

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="80*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="70*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button x:Name="SectionLetterBtn" Content="{Binding Path=EntityGroup.StartingText}" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" BorderBrush="Transparent" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />

    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemContainer" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=EntityGroup.Group}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="80*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" Grid.Column="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>

    public partial class MyListView : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( "Title", typeof( string ), typeof( MyListView ), new PropertyMetadata( null ) );
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ListGroupProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( "ListGroup", typeof( ObservableCollection<MyList> ), typeof( MyListView ), new PropertyMetadata( null ) );

    public MyListView( )
    {
        InitializeComponent( );
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyList> ListGroup
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<MyList>)GetValue( ListGroupProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( ListGroupProperty, value ); }
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue( TitleProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( TitleProperty, value ); }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that I will see 2 buttons show up, but they are empty. All I see are two blue buttons. I'm sure I'm missing something stupid in the code there but just can't find it at all.

Any ideas on this? I'm still pretty new to data binding and having trouble with some of the implementation details. Any help will be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any DataContext-assignment? Are you missing it in your code or am I blind? Just in case: You need to give the grid a DataContext pointing to an instance of your classes either in code or in XAML.

Comment: sprinter252 is right. the xaml part of the code you posted does not contain the DataContext assignment. This is usually specified in the beginning of the <Grid> tag. Please post the entire xaml file contents in a separate code snippet as this is very important since you are using binding in the XAML file

Answer (score 0):

First of all you did not provide all the code. In the xaml code there are binding references to the `EntityGroup` object and I have no clue what that is. But there are a few observations that might help you:

- you are implementing some sort of MVVM, and I didn't see the VM. the first two code snippets are clases belonging to the model the later 2 are to the view
- In order to make your code work make instances in an intermediary class to the class objects and use binding to bind to them. Binding works with instanced objects not with class definitions. Here is a ViewModel that you could use:

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Net;
  using System.Windows;
  using System.Windows.Controls;
  using System.Windows.Documents;
  using System.Windows.Ink;
  using System.Windows.Input;
  using System.Windows.Media;
  using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
  using System.Windows.Shapes;

  namespace **YourNamespace**
  {
      public class ViewModel
      {
          public MyList TheList {get; set;}
          public MyListGrouping ListGrouping {get; set;}

          public ViewModel()
          {
              TheList = new MyList();
              ListGrouping = new MyListGrouping();
              PopulateLists();
          }

          private void PopulateLists()
          {
              TheList.DisplayName = "Testing display name";

              MyList lList = new MyList();
              lList.DisplayName = "List0";
              MyList lList1 = new MyList();
              lList1.DisplayName = "List1";
              MyList lList2 = new MyList();
              lList2.DisplayName = "List2";

              ListGrouping.Title = "Testing title";
              ListGrouping.Group.Add(mList);
              ListGrouping.Group.Add(lList);
              ListGrouping.Group.Add(lList1);
              ListGrouping.Group.Add(lList2);
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- your xaml files are quite messed up and incomplete. However, if you want to make proper bindings their header(s) should contain these lines like this:

  ```
  ...
  xmlns:base="clr-namespace:**YourNamespace**" 
  ...

  <UserControl.Resources>
      <base:ViewModel   x:Key="ViewModel"/>
  </UserControl.Resources>
  ```
- then you should specify the `DataContext` in the xaml file:

  ```
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}">
  ```
- and then you can bind to the properties of the `ViewModel` :

  ```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TheList.DisplayName}" Grid.Column="1" />
  ```

And there you have it. Binding works just fine.

HTH, 
JP